# java.io.StreamCorruptedException in appending data

Tags: java

I have written this java code for appending data in ObjectOutputStream, but this code is throwing (java.io.StreamCorruptedException:). Please help if this code can not work properly then please give an alternative for appending data in ObjectOutputStream.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


class Data implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String time;
    private String note;

    public Data(String time, String note) {
        this.time=time;
        this.note=note;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }
}


public class S extends ObjectOutputStream {

    String t, n;

    public S(FileOutputStream w, String time, String note) throws Exception {
        super(w);
        t=time;
        n=note;
        writeStreamHeader();
    }

    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
        writeObject(new Data(t,n));
        reset();
     }


    public static void rd() {

        Vector v = new Vector();
        Data d;

        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream r = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.cer"));

            for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
                try { v.add(r.readObject()); }
                catch(EOFException exp){
                    r.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
                d = (Data)v.elementAt(i);
                System.out.println(d.getNote()+" "+d.getTime());
            }
        }

        catch(Exception exp) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("ERROR = %s\nCLASS = S", exp.getClass()));
            System.out.println(exp.getClass());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream w  = new FileOutputStream("file.cer",true);
        new S(w,"99:59:59:99","Maxima"); 
        new S(w,"00:00:00:00","Minima"); 
        rd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if this code can not work properly

You are correct. It can not work properly.

> then please give an alternative for appending data in ObjectOutputStream.

`writeStreamHeader()` must do ***nothing*** if the file is being appended to, but it must call `super.writeStreamHeader()` if the file is newly created. It certainly should not call `writeObject()` at any time.